# What is the value of x? Related to Indices.

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

Just some days ago I appeared for a maths exam. In that exam there was a question related to Indices which I was not able to solve. After the exam I even tried solving it in the home next 2 days but without success. Please help! The question is:

$ a = x^4, \ b =x^2, \ c = x^8$ And

$ x^a = 4 $ Then

$ x^b + x^c = \ ?$

If you want to check your answer I have given it after checking the answer sheet online but they didn't provide the solution.

Answer: 258

Comment: I added seperators to your first equation, thought it said $a=x^8, b=x^4, c=x^6$ there ;) Basically you want to find $x$ such that $x^{x^4} = 4$ and then plug it into $x^{x^2} + x^{x^8}$

Comment: Please verify if you mean $a=x^4$ or $a = x^4 b$.

Comment: I mean $ a = x^4, b = x^2 , c = x^8 $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x=a^{1/4}.$$
$$\ln x^a=a\ln x=a\frac{\ln a}4=\ln 4,$$
$$a\ln a=4\ln 4.$$
Clearly, $a=4$ is a solution*.

Then, 
$$b=\sqrt 4=2, c=4^2=16,$$
and
$$x^b+x^c=4^{2/4}+4^{16/4}=2+256=258.$$

*$(a\ln a)'=\ln a+1$ is positive for $a>-1$, so $a\ln a$ is monotonous and the real root is unique.

Comment: Can you explain this more clearly to me without the use of logarithms?

Comment: If you prefer, $x^a=a^{a/4}=4$ has the solution $a=4$, by trial an error (much less obvious than with logarithms). The proof of the uniqueness of the solution requires logarithms anyway.

Comment: Thank You! Also thanks for your quick answer.